# How to set/define environment variables and api_Server in cypress?

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, cypress

Currently, we are using cypress to test our application. We have 2 environments with 2 different api_Servers. I want to define this inside the environment files. I am not sure how to define both the url in same file.

For example,

Environment-1:

baseUrl - https://environment-1.me/
Api_Serever - https://api-environment-1.me/v1

Environment-2:

baseUrl - https://environment-2.me/
Api_Serever - https://api-environment-2.me/v1

So few test cases depend on the baseUrl and 1 test case to check API depends on Api_Serever.

To resolve this I tried to set the baseUrl and Api_Serever inside the config file inside a plugin following this link https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/configuration-api.html#Usage.

I created two config files for 2 environments,

```
{
    "baseUrl": "https://environment-2.me/",
    "env": {
      "envname": "environment-1",
      "api_server": "https://api-environment-1.me/v1"
    }
}
```

Another file similar to this changing the respective endpoints.

plugin file has been modified as,

```
// promisified fs module
const fs = require('fs-extra')
const path = require('path')

function getConfigurationByFile (file) {
  const pathToConfigFile = path.resolve('..', 'cypress', 'config', `${file}.json`)

  return fs.readJson(pathToConfigFile)
}

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  // `on` is used to hook into various events Cypress emits
  // `config` is the resolved Cypress config
    // accept a configFile value or use development by default
    const file = config.env.configFile || 'environment-2'

    return getConfigurationByFile(file)

}
```

inside test cases, whichever refers to the baseUrl we used visit('/')

This works fine when we run a specific file from the command line using the command cypress run --env configFile=environment-2 all the test cases pass, as the visit('/') automatically replaces with the respective environments expect the API test case.

I am not sure how the API test should be modified to call the API endpoint instead of the base URL.

Can somebody help, please?

Thanks,
indhu.

Comment: update: when you access inside the api test case, **cy.request(Cypress.env('api_server'))** by default it is taking only till https://api-environment-1.me and not anything after that. for example, I want to test https://api-environment-1.me/v1/status in that case by default when the request is made inside the test case, only till **https://api-environment-1.me** is being accessed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved.

The best way is to do with a plugin as suggested by their docs (https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/configuration-api.html#Usage).

I kept the structure same as such in my question and in my test case I called it using, **cy.request(Cypress.env('api_server'))**

This solved my issue :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to run tests with different urls. Urls being set in cypress.json or in env file.
Can you configure the urls in cypress.json file as below. I haven't tried though, can you give it a go.

```
{
    "baseUrl":  "https://environment-2.me/",
    "api_server1": "https://api1_url_here",
    "api_server2": "https://api2_url_here"
}
```

Inside the test call pass the urls as below;

```
describe('Test for various Urls', () => {
    it('Should test the base url', () => {
      cy.visit('/')  // this point to baseUrl configured in cypress.json file
      // some tests to continue based on baseUrl..
    })

    it('Should test the api 1 url', () => {
      cy.visit(api_server1)  // this point to api server 1 configured in cypress.json file
      // some tests to continue based on api server1..
    })

  it('Should test the api 2 url', () => {
      cy.visit(api_server2)  // this point to api server 2 configured in cypress.json file
      // some tests to continue based on api server2..
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, @soccerway. I followed a similar approach as yours :)

Comment: Awesome, keep on thinking if there are other ways to achieve this. If you are happy accept,upvote my answer so that I will get my internet points:)

Comment: I did vote ;) but no reputation so it won't be displayed